# angular 2 how to custom interface like onInit

Tags: angular, typescript

Here I have a menu service like below...

**menu.service.ts**

```
    import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
        import {
            Http,
            Request,
            Response,
            RequestMethod,
            Headers,
            URLSearchParams,
            RequestOptions,
            ResponseContentType,
        } from '@angular/http';
        import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
        import * as _ from 'lodash'

        @Injectable()
        export class MenuService {

            constructor(public http: Http) {}
            IsOnReady = false;
            _onReady: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>(true);

            data = [];
            getData() {

            return  this.http.get('/api/Menus').subscribe(data => {      
                    this.data = data.json()
                    this.IsOnReady = true;
                    this._onReady.emit('menu is ready');
                });

            }


            onReady(callback) {
                if (this.IsOnReady) {
                    callback();
                }
                else {
                    this._onReady.subscribe(r => {
                        callback();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

In another page, I always need to  call `menu.onReady` to get menu data, then do something after...

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuService } from '../../../services/menu.service';


export class NewsComponentBase implements OnInit{

    NewsCategoryID:string

    constructor(public menu: MenuService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.menu.onReady(() => this.active());
    }

    active() {
        this.NewsCategoryID= this.menu.data[0].NewsCategoryID;
    }
}
```

How to achieve an interface like angular's `onInit`， some code like

```
import { MenuService,MenuOnReady} from '../../../services/menu.service';

export class NewsComponentBase implements MenuOnready {

    NewsCategoryID:string

    constructor(public menu: MenuService) {
    }

    MenuOnReady () {
        this.NewsCategoryID= this.menu.data[0].NewsCategoryID;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are subscribing to an event. Not seen that done anywhere, is it even working? I think a proper way to do this is using a Subject that you subscribe to from your two other components. If you want to customize a lifecycle hook then using ngDoCheck is usually the way to go.

Comment: Hi, thanks! it is working well, use "menu.OnReady".
I think the interface "MenuOnReady" it's not belong angular's lifecycle hook. It's belong "getData()" function, when "getData" got data, then every class that implements "MenuOnready" can use menu data directly

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not thinking the 'angular 2 way'

If we follow the official guide https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Your method `getData` should return a promise or an observable and you have to subscribe in the ngOnInit method.

Your code should be something like this:

```
 import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
        import {
            Http,
            Request,
            Response,
            RequestMethod,
            Headers,
            URLSearchParams,
            RequestOptions,
            ResponseContentType,
        } from '@angular/http';
        import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
        import * as _ from 'lodash'

        @Injectable()
        export class MenuService {

            constructor(public http: Http) {}

            getData():Promise<any> {
                return  this.http.get('/api/Menus');
            }
        }

import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuService } from '../../../services/menu.service';


export class NewsComponentBase implements OnInit{

    NewsCategoryID:string

    constructor(public menu: MenuService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.menu.getData().then(data => {      
                    this.data = data.json()
                   this.active();
                });
    }

    active() {
        this.NewsCategoryID= this.menu.data[0].NewsCategoryID;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should quote the section of "the official guide" that you are reffering to. Also, some comments in your code snippet wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
The method "getData" is not the point in my question
I just really wanna to know how to achieve an interface like onInit.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not answer the original question.